# Retrieve Customer Entity in Dynamics CRM 2016

Tags: dynamics-crm

As we know Dynamics CRM has a specific attribute value: Customer. This value combines the Client and Account entity, but I'm blind or MSDN doesn't have specification about retrieving this field in query.
For example:

```cs
QueryByAttribute query = new QueryByAttribute(entName);
query.ColumnSet = new ColumnSet(new String[] { searchAttr });
query.Attributes.Add(searchAttr);
query.Values.Add(searchValue);

EntityCollection retrived = service.RetrieveMultiple(query);
```

This code accepts entity name and searches the attribute's name and value, but when I run it I don't know which type of entity I get from my DataSouce: Client or Account.
So the question is: is it possible to retrieve Customer entity in one query?

Comment: Check `.LogicalName` of each record

Comment: Yes. I'm doing it now. But I just wondering: maybe there is a specific way to work with this type?

Comment: I'm not aware of any

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you must first know which entity you are trying to retrieve.

---

Get the value held within the Customer field as an `EntityReference`:

```cs
var customer = entity.GetAttributeValue<EntityReference>("customerid");
```

Get the `LogicalName` of the `EntityReference`:

```cs
var customerEntity = customer.LogicalName;
```

Comment: Thanks. It's sad because I work with raw data and don't know what kind of client I would get.

Comment: @KrivitskiyGrigoriy what do you mean when you say you work with raw data? If you're exporting `customer` data to excel, it should be possible to retrieve the customer type

Comment: Company has an employee somewhere in Russia. When he sold the product to customer, he fill excel file on his mobile phone and send it to main office via e-mail. When this mail received by mail server this file as attachment parse by specific template and records created in CRM. It's kinda complicated in the current moment.